# H.264 video packet duration missing

Tags: h.264, ffprobe

I have H.264 files that, when I run FFprobe on them, like this:

```
ffprobe -i h264_file.ts -show_packets -select_streams v
```

...it shows that each video packet has no values for duration, and no value for duration_time, like this:

> ```
> ...
> [PACKET]
> codec_type=video
> stream_index=0
> pts=8098077717
> pts_time=89978.641300
> dts=8098077717
> dts_time=89978.641300
> **duration=N/A
> duration_time=N/A
> convergence_duration=N/A
> convergence_duration_time=N/A**
> size=2354
> pos=14633920
> flags=_
> [/PACKET]
> ...
> ```

My question is, other than re-encoding the file, and assuming I know the source to be 60 fps, is there a way to correct this video packet duration?

I know I can do it by re-encoding - I have done so successfully.  But I am wondering if there is an easier and faster way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you need duration? The effective duration is the delta with the pts of the next frame.

Comment: Without the packet duration, MythTV thinks the transport stream file has a duration twice as long as it actually is.  I think it defaults to 30fps, but this source generates files at 60 fps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sample of your file so I don't know if this fixes it or not, but have you tried a simple remux?

```
ffmpeg -y -i h264_file.ts -c copy remuxed.ts
```

This is also basically the same thing, but helpful if you want video and audio in separate files before you remux:

```
ffmpeg -y -i h264_file.ts -map 0:0 -c:v copy -muxdelay 0 video.ts -map 0:1 -c:a copy -muxdelay 0 audio.ts
ffmpeg -y -copyts -i video.ts -i audio.ts -c copy remuxed.ts
```

You could also try reencoding audio but copying video.  Encoding audio but copying video will be fast and usually concerns about reencoding loss is a lot less significant with audio.  (Use audio synchronization, see `-async` in documentation.)

Comment: I hadn't considered re-muxing it - thanks for the suggestion.  I will try it and reply back.

Comment: Unfortunately, the re-muxing did not fix it.  Specifically, I tried the two separate steps you listed.  I also tried:  `ffmpeg -i ./file.ts -c copy file_remuxed.ts` `ffmpeg -i ./file.ts -c copy -vsync drop file_remuxed_vsync_drop.ts` `ffmpeg -i ./file.ts -c copy -r 60 file_remuxed_r60.ts` `ffmpeg -i ./file.ts -c copy -r 30 file_remuxed_r30.ts` All resulted in packet durations of N/A when examined using ffprobe.